# Is this behavior in a programming language inconsistent?

Tags: pl.programming-languages, type-theory, lambda-calculus, type-inference

I'm developing a tiny programming language to try to wrap my head around type inference, and I'm trying to figure out if its behavior makes sense or not. Here's the problem:

The identity function `\x.x` can't be unified to a single type, but applied to something, it can, i.e. `(\x.x) 10 : Int`. However, right now, the expression:

```
((\x.x) (\x.x)) 10
```

can't be unified, because the expression `(\x.x) (\x.x)` doesn't have a single type. The type checker doesn't do any evaluation, so it can't tell that the above expression is equivalent to `\x.x`. The type checker only sees the expression, tries to determine the type of it, and fails before trying to apply it to `10`.

Is this typical behavior, or am I being inconsistent with my type inference?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, your type inference seems incomplete. This example can be dealt with fairly trivially, by computing the respective type equations, e.g. in the style Hindley/Milner does it.

Alpha-renaming the example makes it easier to follow:

```
((\x.x) (\y.y)) 10
```

For maximum clarity, let's start by assigning type variables to each sub expression:

- x : A
- (\x.x) : B
- y : C
- (\y.y) : D
- (\x.x) (\y.y) : E
- 10 : F
- ((\x.x) (\y.y)) 10 : G

Now, the typing rules of the language impose certain equality constraints for each language construct:

- From the typing rule for lambda, applied to (\x.x), it follows that B = A -> A
- Likewise, D = C -> C
- From the typing rule for application, applied to (\x.x) (\y.y), it follows that A = D and E = D
- From the typing rule for integers it follows that F = Int
- From the typing rule for application, applied to (...) 10, it follows that E = F -> G

In summary, this yields the following equations:

1. B = A -> A
2. D = C -> C
3. A = D
4. E = D
5. F = Int
6. E = F -> G

   Now you just solve the equations using unification:
7. From (2) and (3) it follows that A = C -> C
8. From (2) and (4) it follows that E = C -> C
9. From (5) and (6) it follows that E = Int -> G
10. From (8) and (9) it follows that C -> C = Int -> G, and thus, C = Int and C = G, and thus, G = Int
11. From (7) and (10) it follows that A = Int -> Int

A and C are the types you are ultimately interested in, because they are the ones you have to assign to x and y, respectively. They yield the typed term

```
((\x:(Int->Int).x) (\y.Int.y)) 10
```

Its overall type is G = Int.